# Break string into separate lines

Tags: python, string

I have this string in python:

```
 CS121P: Bunyan, John Henry, Matthew Luther, Martin  CS132S: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John  CS202H: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John
```

I need it to look like this:

```
CS121P: Bunyan, John Henry, Matthew Luther, Martin  
CS132S: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John  
CS202H: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Is the code on which you want to split is always starting CS*** ?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. What have you tried so far. Post your code [mre] and ask specific question about a problem you cannot solve.

Comment: @GedasMiksenas no it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
inp = "CS121P: Bunyan, John Henry, Matthew Luther, Martin  CS132S: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John  CS202H: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John"
lines = re.findall(r'\b(CS\d+[A-Z]+:.*?)\s*(?=CS\d+[A-Z]+|$)', inp)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

This prints:

```
CS121P: Bunyan, John Henry, Matthew Luther, Martin
CS132S: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John
CS202H: Calvin, John Knox, John Owen, John
```

Comment: this works for the three lines, but what if I had more lines in it? The actual string is longer and I need to do the same thing but more lines. I ran it with the original string and it looped through the first three only.

Comment: My answer should work for any number of lines, assuming you have a single flat string as your question implies.

Comment: I think it's because some of the first words are ACC210 and MA262

Comment: Try: `re.findall(r'\b([A-Z0-9]+:.*?)\s*(?=[A-Z0-9]+:|$)', inp)` ... next time you post please include sample data which captures all possible inputs.  The regex in this comment should work for you.